# Do all the tasks across agent jobs in the pipeline run on the same agent?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm learning about azure pipelines. By default you get 1 free parallel job for x number of minutes.

1. A pipeline contains number of tasks. And atleast 1 job. All the tasks in the pipeline (across multiple jobs) run on the same agent?
2. Does 1 parallel job means 1 pipeline execution containing 2 or more jobs? or only 2 jobs?

Answer (score 0):

1. No. Each job will run on a new agent.
2. 1 parallel job means that one job can run at a time. Two parallel jobs means that two parallel jobs can run at a time, each on a separate agent. And so on.

Comment: I need some more clarity about point 2. So for example - by default Azure gives 1 Microsoft hosted and 1 self hosted agent. If my pipeline has got 2 jobs where 1 runs on microsoft hosted and other runs on self-hosted agent, then does that mean that 2 jobs can run at a time?

Comment: Yes. Refer to the licensing documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/licensing/concurrent-jobs?view=azure-devops&tabs=self-hosted

Comment: The link says `Each running job consumes a parallel job` - Since 1 agent can run 1 job at a time, I assume I will will 2 parallel jobs to be able to run my situation (described in above comment)? Then how is the answer in your comment `Yes`?

Comment: The number of parallel jobs is separately defined for Microsoft hosted agents and self-hosted agents. You get one of each by default. If you had 3 licenses for self-hosted agents and 1 for Microsoft-hosted, you could run 4 jobs in parallel, as long as 3 were on private agents.